# How can I make my python program install modules automatically on new computers?

Tags: python, module, pip

So I've written a program in python that I want to use on different computers, but to do this I need to install modules by opening up the command prompt and using "pip install ".

Is there a way to do this in the program without having to open the command prompt?

Comment: In this thread, they talk about how to run terminal commands from Python.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/how-to-execute-a-program-or-call-a-system-command

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the built-in `pip` module, which allows you to install python packages within your code.

e.g.

```
import pip
pip.main(["install", "pygame"])
```

in order to check for your package, you could use a try-except and check for an ImportError

Answer (score 0):

I suspect if there is any way but here's the trick:

```
import os
os.system('pip install --user <module>')
```

And if you have many different packages to install, you may create `requirements.txt` file and just do `pip install -r requirements.txt`